# how to access the failover virtual machine in Azure . I am not seeing the Public IP address. Also this is my trial account

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, failover

How to access the failover virtual machine in Azure from the open network . It does not show the Public IP in overview section. This is my trial account . Any answer would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to an Azure VM from the internet, the VM must have a public IP address associated with it. You can associate a public IP address to a virtual machine follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/associate-public-ip-address-vm).

For example, with Azure CLI, you can run

```
az login

az network public-ip create --name myVMPublicIP --resource-group myResourceGroup

az network nic ip-config update \
  --name ipconfigmyVM \
  --nic-name myVMVMNic \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --public-ip-address myVMPublicIP
```

Comment: Do you still have any questions? If my post is helpful, could you please click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in to accept it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).